# operator new with negative size

Tags: c++

In C++11 if we try to allocate array with negative size using global operator new, it will throw std::bad_array_new_length, but what about C++98 / C++03? Is it UB or will throw std::bad_alloc?

```
int main()
{
   int* ptr = new int[-1];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program is incorrect if the size is negative 5.3.4p6 from the C++03 standard:

> Every constant-expression in a direct-new-declarator shall be an integral constant expression (5.19) and evaluate to a **strictly positive value**. The expression in a direct-new-declarator shall have integral or enumeration type (3.9.1) with a **non-negative value**.

The above quote covers `new T[a][b];`, where `b` is the *constant-expression* according to the grammar and `a` is the *expression* (only the first dimension).

Comment: I knew it was in there somewhere. :)

Comment: It says about constant-expression in a noptr-new-declarator (this rule also apply to C++11), but what about non-constant-expression?

Comment: `const size_t s = -1; int* ptr = new int[s];` Is `s` strictly positive?

Comment: @PiotrNycz In C, definitely, I'm not 100% sure about C++, but methinks `size_t` is specified to be an unsigned type there too. Edit: Yep, it is.

Comment: @bames53: Yes, I failed to copy enough of the paragraph. The first sentence deals with all but the first dimension (which must be strictly positive constant expressions). The second sentence covers the first dimension that is a (possibly not constant) expression that only needs to be non-negative.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Yes, the type `size_t` is unsigned, so `-1` will be converted to `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` which is *very* positive.

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: Updated with the second sentence from the paragraph (I failed to quote that initially).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas so my example is not "ill-formed". Then why the OP's example is ill-formed (according to your first sentence)?

Comment: @PiotrNycz Because the type of the expression `-1` is `int`, so it evaluates to a negative value. `int *i = new int[(size_t)-1];` would be okay.

Comment: Maybe this quote? "If n is negative, the effect of
new float[n][5] is undefined."

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: That is from an example, and as such is not normative. The reason the example is undefined is because the text before the example (the quote in this answer).

Comment: "shall have" means UB? I think that it's stands for ill-formed code

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: Considering that a non-constant expression cannot be checked at compile time, I am inclined to thing that it is *undefined behavior, no diagnostic required*.

Comment: So, it is UB in C++98 / C++03 prior to "The expression in a direct-new-declarator shall have integral or enumeration type (3.9.1) with a non-negative value" and throw std::bad_array_new_length exception in C++11 because of "If the value of that expression is less than zero ... no storage
is obtained and the new-expression terminates by throwing an exception of a type that would match a
handler (15.3) of type std::bad_array_new_length". Right?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That would make sense, but looking at the definitions of 'ill-formed', 'well-formed', and 'diagnosable rules' it looks to me like a non-constant expression that evaluates to a negative value in a new expression is ill-formed code in C++98 which must be diagnosed... unless I'm missing some explicit notation that no diagnostic is required or which describes this as resulting in undefined behavior. This looks like a defect in the C++98 standard.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas And if there are -1 as constant-expression, we __must__ have compile-time error both in C++98 / C++03 and C++11, right?

Comment: Because there are no compile-time error for code like "int* ptr = new int[-1];" in gcc with C++11 mode

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: The *constant-expression* and *expression* in the quote above refer to the grammar in the beginning of the section, not as to whether the actual value is a constant expression. That is, the requirements for *expression* are the requirements on the first dimension, which for C++11 means that it will compile and throw. The program is ill-formed, but I don't think the standard requires a diagnostic (i.e. it is a quality of implementation).

Answer (score 2):

You get this for `int a[-1]`:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:4: error: size of array ‘b’ is negative
```

And this for `int* a = new int[-1]` (runtime error):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Comment: gcc will not give you an error. For other compilers you must use non-constant expression for array size

Comment: It's not me. And yes, i know the output. I asked about standard qoutes.

Comment: -1 from me. You appear to be (recently) active in C++, so you should know (or learn fast) that compilers tell **nothing** about the language. C++ is mandated by the Standard, not by what compilers produce.

Comment: The standard says exactly what you downvoted in a now deleted answer - the size has to be an unsigned type.

Comment: Well, he did ask if it throwed a `bad_alloc`. I didn't know the answer so I wend and tried it on gcc :)

Comment: Then why does it compile? Shouldn't it gove an error at compile time?

Comment: @alestanis short answers - compilers aren't very good at respecting standards. See variable length arrays, `main` with `void` return type & many more.

Comment: It compiles because it's legal. The **type** that operator new takes is unsigned; the value that you pass to it doesn't have to be. If it's negative, the value gets converted to the unsigned type, which is generally something you don't want. But most of the time it will fail at runtime, because the result of the conversion is quite large, and too large to allocate successfully.

Comment: This is why I love SO: I try to answer something and I'm the one that finishes learning things :)

Comment: It seems this is a controversial topic (judging by the comments on David's answer), so I'll make my downvote clear - I'm not stating the answer is wrong because it advocates that the code is correct or not, it's wrong because it relies on a compiler/runtime to explain it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I know, I understood my mistake with your first comment :) promise I won't be naive about gcc anymore

Answer (score 2):

the definition of new[] states that it requires an unsigned integer also typedefed to `size_t`. So that *should* never compile.

See here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t (which is an unsigned int).